# Rename bulk files

Tags: bash, python3, rename

I need to rename the '*.mp3' songs but I don't know how to change name for each and every song in a directory. Does anyone know how to do it?

I need to rename my .mp3 files like this:

```
Aaaa.mp3
Aaab.mp3
Aaac.mp3
Aaad.mp3
...
Aaaz.mp3
Baaa.mp3
Baab.mp3
...
...
Zzzz.mp3
```

I know how to change the name for a single file. But, not prefer to change each name manually.

Comment: Which OS are you using? If you're using windows, it will be easy for me to share with u may solution. It's very easy.

Comment: I'm using Both windows and ubuntu. It'd be helpful if you share your solution.

Comment: @Dr.Xavier  Windows related Q/A here on AskUbunutu are off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first generate the filename template and store them in array mode, then travers on `.mp3` files and rename them with the name read from the array:

```
arr_name=( $(printf '%s\n' {A..Z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}) )
i=0; for file in ./*.mp3; do echo mv "$file" "${arr_name[i++]}.mp3"; done
unset arr_name  #unset array after all
```

---

```
mv ./files1.mp3 Aaaa.mp3
mv ./files2.mp3 Aaab.mp3
mv ./files3.mp3 Aaac.mp3
…
```

remove `echo` in front of the `mv` command to get ride of the dry-run to perform rename on files.

Comment: Can you help me with how to generate the filename template and store it in an array? I am new to Linux so I don't know much about it. I'd be happy if you can explain it in detail

Comment: @Raj that's already in the answer 

Comment: Got it, bro. Thankyou!